# Is it practical to replace two sprockets on a cassette?

Tags: road-bike, gears, derailleur, cassette

My bike has 53/39T chainrings and a cassette with 12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,25 sprockets, but I like to ride up steep mountain roads. Is it possible (without great expense) to replace two sprockets to make it a little easier to spin instead of mash?

My rear derailleur is a Shimano RD-6500. I tried checking online, but I couldn't find a clear description of what the maximum sprocket size it supports is. Would it be practical to replace, say, the 23T sprocket with a 24T and the 25T with a 27T?

Or is there something else I should be considering to make the gearing a little more friendly for spinning on steep roads?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you will need to get a whole new cassette, the largest 3 rings are connected to each other, you cannot just purchase individual cogs. You may want to get a new chain as you will probably need to make a chain length change with jumping from a 25T to 27T or 28T largest cog.

Do you know if you have the SS or the GS?

With the SS (short cage) you can go as big as 28T, Shimano sells a 12-28 cassette.
With the GS (long cage) you can go as big as 27T, look for a 12-27 cassette.

Another option for easier spinning is a new compact crankset, Shimano comes as a 34/50, but you give up high end speed.

**EDIT:**

Added screenshot of the relevant tech info for the RD-6500. Hope it's helpful.

[image: Snip of Shimano RD-6500 Tech Docs]

Although the derailleur has the capacity for 28t as an SS derailleur, Shimano never produced a 9 speed 28t cog. Therefore, as a practical matter, the 27t is the largest option available for the RD-6500 Ultegra 9 speed derailleur from Shimano. There are [cassettes available from Interloc Racing Design](http://www.interlocracing.com/cassettes_steel.html) which fill this missed niche.

[image: CS-6500 cassette options]

Comment: A very great answer!

Comment: How do I know if I have the SS or the GS? The stamp on the inside of the derailleur that has the model number does not say either SS or GS. If it's relevant, I believe the derailleur is from around 2003.

Comment: By the way, thanks for clarifying that I would have to get a whole new cassette. I was hoping that this wasn't the case, but it's good to know. :)

Comment: Seems worth pointing out that if you switch to a compact (34/50) crankset and an 11-27 or 11-28 cassette you will keep the high end speed. 50:11 is a higher gear ratio than 53:12, actually a smidge higher than 54:12.

Comment: freiheit, but that would require replacing both the crankset and the cassette. Maybe when I'm rich and famous... :)

Comment: Cassettes are cheap anyway.

Comment: @StephenTouset, donations are graciously accepted. :)

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that for 10 speed (RD-6600-6800, and 7800-7900) the 28t cassette is only supported by Shimano's 2011 and 2012 Ultegra and only 2012 Dura Ace groups on the SS derailleur(Short Cage), although that may change for lower groups soon, and that 27t is the maximum for 2011 and previous years. A 2003 group will be 9 speed, and therefore regardless of level will not support a 28t cassette because they did not produce a 28t 9 speed Ultegra cassette. The largest option was a 12/27 from Shimano. There *are* IRD and other aftermarket cassettes available.

Comment: @GlennGervais: I edited your answer to include the TechDocs info from the Shimano Service Instructions.

Comment: @amcnabb: The derailleur cage length indicates the SS or GS status of a derailleur. Most likely, you have an SS as the GS was designed for a bike with a triple front crank set as of 2003, and would only be on your bike if it's been replaced, or improperly spec'd to begin with.

Comment: @zenbike: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, I can't guarantee that it's an SS because I know that the previous owner upgraded the rear derailleur. They knew what they're doing, so it's probably still true that it's an SS, but it's hard to know for sure. Too bad it's not labeled one way or the other.

Comment: It doesn't need a label, because the difference is physically obvious by sight. You can measure the distance between pulley centers, or upload a photo, and I'll tell you which one it is.

Comment: Thanks @zenbike for the edits, great stuff! - SRAM makes a 9 speed cassette (PG950) in 12-28 on Amazon (US store for $26)

Comment: They do. Have you used it? My experience with SRAM cassettes on Shimano drive trains is that they are technically compatible, but that shifting performance suffers drastically. I'd be interested in feedback from you on the 28t cassette, if you have any?

Comment: On my cross bike, I have used SRAM with Shimano 105 derailleur and did not notice shifting issues. It was a hodge poge drive train of Shimano, SRAM, FSA, Wipperman. My MTB I still run SRAM (12/34 though) with Shimano XTR, FSA crankset, no issues with rear changes, but get chain suck (still after new inner chainring, new chain...).

Answer (score 3):

You can buy individual cassette sprockets! You don't need to buy a whole new cassette.

I don't know where you are, but SJS Cycles in the UK stock individual Shimano sprockets, and Rose Bikes in Germany do too.

Another route is to use a Marchisio sprocket. These can be made up in any combination of ratios you like. Again, you'll need to do a bit of Googling to find a stockist, but you will be able to order individual sprockets or a cassette in any combination of ratios you like. They are Shimano and Campag compatible.

It's also worth looking at SRAM, Miche, BBB and other compatible cassettes if you can't find exactly the ratio you want in Shimano or Campag.

Comment: You can buy loose cogs ( and even the 3 cog integrated part from ultegra and up ) but if you want to make your own custom cassettes, it's often more cost effective to just buy whole clusters and mix and match.